# Sublime text and regex, catch two strings?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I am using SublimeText3. I have an expression as follows

```
\eq{\label{LABEL}
data1
data2
}
```

I would like to be able to catch `LABEL` and

```
data1
data2
```

So that later I can use them, say by referring to them as `$1` and `$2`.

I can catch between `\eq{}` by `(?<=^\\eq\{)(([\s\S]*?))(?=^\})`.

I can catch between `\label{}` by `(?<=\\label\{)((.*?))(?=\})`.

How do I catch both?

Comment: Why you want to catch the both? Did you want to replace the match with another string?

Comment: yes I want to replace with `\eq{LABEL}{data}`

Comment: add the expected output in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sublime, you could use the following expression:

```
\\eq{\\label\{([^}]+)\}([^}]+)
```

Comment: Hi, I modified to `\\eq\{\\label\{([^}]+)\}\K([^}]+)` as your expression didn't work. However, it gives me only the data.

Comment: Try it now, should give both.

Comment: Just added a couple of backslashes to be `\\eq\{\\label\{([^}]+)\}([^}]+)` it does work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want something like this

```
/\{(\w+)\}\n([^\}]*)/g
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/rS7aF4/1)

`{(\w+)}` will look for a string between `{` and `}` and will put it in `$1` and `\n` is a new line character and `([^}]*)` will capture anything until a `}` is encountered, and put it in `$2`

Comment: wow! much appreciated, although, does it work in SublimeText3? at least not for me.

Comment: @PepeToro just use `{(\w+)}\n([^}]*)`

Comment: So, I should say I am using the Search and Replace tool of ST3. If I copy paste your expression, there is nothing. If I change the first part of your expression to `\{(\w+)\}` it does find the text between `{}` but the next part doesn't work. I'll keep trying though.

Comment: @PepeToro now try this `\{(\w+)\}\n([^\}]*)`

Comment: although this does work, it works too general. I mean, any other similar expression is also found. I guess I can try to work out a solution based on your proposal.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this also,

```
(?<=^\\eq\{)\\label{(.*?)\}([\s\S]*?)(?=^\})
```